# Hanging my emacs with a while loop. How to recover?

Tags: crash

The following loop hangs my emacs (even when called with -q) to the point that I have to force quit it.

```
(let ((buffs (buffer-list)))
  (while buffs
    (delq (car buffs) buffs)
    (print (cadr buffs))))
```

I don't understand why this should happen, but is there something I can do to recover from a hanging Emacs?

Comment: My understanding of the word "crash" is "exiting badly" possibly with a segfault or something like that. Apparently this is not what you mean.

Comment: You are right. Hanging is a better word. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

I guess since youre saving the result of buffer-list, buffs never evaluates to a falsy value.
You should update the buffs variable by seting it to the return vaulue of your delq.

```
(setq buffs (delq (car buffs) buffs))
```